# Android Heap Space Errors

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All

I'm trying to embed a ROS Android application into my android device however I get the following errors

```
[2012-11-27 10:20:22 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
[2012-11-27 10:20:22 - org.ros.android.android_tutorial_pubsub.MainActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
```

in the console output of eclipse.

The project is based off the android_tutorial_pubsub project with my own NodeMain incorporated  into it.

My Project has all the JARs from the android_tutorial_pubsub/libs wrapped up into a user library (a solution on stack overflow which didn't fix the problem).

The org.ros.android_gingerbread_mr1. is included in the build path, as when I include it as a library under the project>>properties>>android i get a conflict between its JARs and the ones from android_tutorial_pubsub. So its included on project>>properties>>Java Build Path as a required Project. (allows the MainActivity to compile and doesn't conflict JARs.

I've also adjusted the eclipse.ini file Xss property to 1024 as suggested by some.

Anyone have any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49179/android-heap-space-errors/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I published the last line of the error in Google and came up with a couple of different responses the one that worked is listed here in stack oveflow:

[stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space)

I increased my
Xms values to 512 as suggested and the program advanced.

cheers

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0